# Active Directory - DNs Forwarders in c#

Tags: c#, dns, active-directory, ldap

Can we check Dns Forwarders configured on each domain controller in C# .NET? Could not find any classes supporting this.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using WSManConnectionInfo and Runspace, I could achieve fetching the desired details.

```
        WSManConnectionInfo connInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://ServerName:5985/wsman"));
        Collection<PSObject> output = null;
        string command = "Get-DnsServerForwarder";
        using (Runspace remoteRS = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connInfo))
        {
            remoteRS.Open();
            using (var pShell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                pShell.Commands.AddCommand(command);
                output = pShell.Invoke();
            }
        }
```